# In wikipedia it is referred that Remote Socket Address is the Client Socket Address but i doubt that

Tags: networking

In the context of Network Socket , which one is the REMOTE SOCKET ADDRESS?? Does the Client Socket Address refer to the Remote Socket Address?

Comment: These kinds of questions don't scale well here.  I can imagine a half-dozen questions related to terminology, on a single Wikipedia article, asked by the same person.  And you didn't even link the Wikipedia article.  Use a dictionary, perhaps?

Comment: I want to know the simplest interpretation of the following sub-text as given in wikipedia...itz given below.

" A server may create several concurrently established TCP sockets with the same local port number and local IP address, each mapped to its own server-child process, serving its own client process. They are treated as different sockets by the operating system, since the remote socket address (the client IP address and/or port number) are different; i.e. since they have different socket pair tuples."

Answer (score 5):

> In the context of Network Socket , which one is the REMOTE SOCKET ADDRESS??

Both sockets are remote, one from the other. If, in some specific context, you label one socket "local", the other must be remote. You give no such context.

> Does the Client Socket Address refer to the Remote Socket Address?

In the context of the client process, its socket is local and the server's is remote.

In the context of the server process, its socket is local and the client's is remote.

---

You might as well ask, "which end of the pipe is called the far end?"  The answer depends on which end you're holding at the time.